# Mixing text and functions inside an if/else with MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code inside a partial view:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "ChangePassword", "Account") &#124; Html.ActionLink("Log off", "LogOff", "Account")
}
else
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account")
}
```

Expected output (with appropriate links to actions):

- If logged in: Hello Jim | Log off
- If not logged in: Log in

However, this results in errors:

- Within VS, The word "Hello" has an error on it: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Hello'" and "&#" has "Expression expected"
- In the browser I get "CS1040: Preprocessor directives must appear as the first non-whitespace character on a line"

If I put a `<p>...</p>` around the line beginning with "Hello" the error goes away.

There is obviously some syntax error with my mixing calls to `@Html` and text within the same line. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The contents of a code block (`{ ... }`) are expected to be code, not markup.

If you want to put text directly in a code block, you have three choices:

- Wrap it in any HTML tag
- Wrap it in the special Razor `<text>` tag, which will just render the text without the tag
- Prepend the line with `@:`, which is equivalent

See [SottGu's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx).

Comment: I disagree with the statement that the contents of a code block are not expected to be markup. The whole point of Razor is to be able to intermingle C#/VB.NET code and markup.

Comment: @JLRishe: Yes, but there is no way for Razor to know that `Hello` is expected to be markup rather than code.

Comment: That's true, but `Hello` isn't markup. :) A more accurate statement would be "The contents of a code block are expected to be code or markup (tags), not plain text."